# webpy 404 error with strange URL

Tags: python, apache, http-status-code-404, web.py

I am running a webpy + Apache server. When I try to navigate to /projects/Index (which has always worked in the past), I get a 404 not found error. When I check ctx.fullpath, it says the requested path is /redirect:/code.py/projects.pyc/Index/Index, when it is in fact just /projects/Index. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it? 
In my main application file I have this code:

```
urls = (
    "/stream","stream",
    "/","index",
    "/projects","projects",
    "/prj/(.+)", "projects",
    "/projects/(.+)", "projects",
    "/files","files",
    "/login", "login",
    "/Firewall", collector.app_firewall,
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())
session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('/var/www/sessions'), initializer={'count': 0})
application = app.wsgifunc()
class Content:
    root = "/var/www/static" #default document root for open()
    title = "Brian Barrett" #default title
content = Content() 
content.user = "login"

class index:
    def GET(self):
        content.title = "Brian Barrett"
        content.content = open(content.root + "/index.html", "r").read()
        return render.layout(content)

class projects:
    def GET(self, project):
        content.title = project
        content.content = "Project not found! Check <a href='/projects/index'>here</a>."
        if project.endswith("js"):
            return open(content.root + "/projects/" + project).read()
        #the following returns the index of all projects
        if project.lower() == "index" or not project or project == "": 
            content.title = "Projects"
            content.content = open(content.root + "/prj/projects.html", "r").read()
            return render.layout(content)
        #find project in /static/projects, return that
        else:
            html_projects = [] # new array
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/var/www/static/prj/"):
                for file in files:
                    if file.endswith(".html"): #if it is an html file
                        html_projects.append(os.path.join(root, file)) #put HTML in array
            for p in html_projects:
                if p.find(str(project.lower())) != -1: #if the filename has the request in it
                    content.content = open(p, "r").read() # set content to said HTML
            content.title = project.replace("_"," ") # important! links must have capitalized titles
            return render.layout(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I had a python bytecode file in the same directory called projects.pyc and it was apparently attempting to redirect the user there. I deleted the file and it resolved the issue. Still confused about why it did that, though.